# Check equals between multiple columns values in a row?

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

quick question here

I have a table like this

```
COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2 COLUMN_3 COLUMN_4 COLUMN_5  SAME
X1       X1       X1       X1       X1        X1
X1       X2       X1       X1       X3        DIFFERENT
X1       NULL     X1       X1       NULL      X1
X1       NULL     X2       NULL     X3        DIFFERENT
```

So basically what i want to know if all the colums between column_1 and column 5 are the same , then get a column with the value (row 1 ).If not all are the columns are different then get a column with different (row 2) . These rows can contain null values (row 3, row 4) but they do not affect the flag.

BTW, The columns type is STRING.

Im looking to do this in teradata or oracle.

Thanks a lot

PS: Column_1 is not null it can contain values from x1 to x5. Column_2 to Column_5 can be null.

Comment: What if all are NULL?

Comment: Is column_1 always x1?  If all columns are X3, is Same = X3?

Comment: column 1 is not null

Comment: column_1 can be x1, x2, x3,x4,x5. Basically, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the actual data you are working with, you could temporarily unpivot the data as rows, and from there your problem is easy to solve. Here I'm assuming there is a primary key in your table called `row_id`.

Using your example data...

```
with your_table as(
   select 1 as row_id, 'X1' as c1, 'X1' as c2, 'X1' as c3, 'X1' as c4, 'X1' as c5 from dual union all
   select 2 as row_id, 'X1' as c1, 'X2' as c2, 'X1' as c3, 'X1' as c4, 'X3' as c5 from dual union all
   select 3 as row_id, 'X1' as c1, null as c2, 'X1' as c3, 'X1' as c4, null as c5 from dual union all
   select 4 as row_id, 'X1' as c1, null as c2, 'X2' as c3, null as c4, 'X3' as c5 from dual
)
select * 
  from your_table; 

ROW_ID   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
------   --  --  --  --  --
1        X1  X1  X1  X1  X1
2        X1  X2  X1  X1  X3
3        X1      X1  X1   
4        X1      X2      X3
```

Using the unpivot operator like below, would turn all non-null column values into each own record. Notice how the null values are missing from the output.

```
select * 
  from your_table unpivot(colval for colname in(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5));

row_id   colname  colval
------   -------  ------
1            C1       X1
1            C2       X1
1            C3       X1
1            C4       X1
1            C5       X1
2            C1       X1
2            C2       X2
2            C3       X1
2            C4       X1
2            C5       X3
3            C1       X1
3            C3       X1
3            C4       X1
4            C1       X1
4            C3       X2
4            C5       X3
```

...And from here it is easy to solve your problem.

```
select row_id
      ,case when count(distinct colval) = 1 -- There is only one value across columns    
            then min(colval)                -- All are same, just pick one
            else 'DIFFERENT'
        end one_value
  from your_table unpivot (colval for colname in(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5))
 group -- Group by to reassemble the record 
    by row_id
```

**Edit:**
After clarifications about C1 and nullability, the problem is much simpler:

```
select case when not c1 = all(c2,c3,c4,c5) then 'DIFFERENT' else c1 end
  from your_table;
```

But I'm anyway leaving the old answer, because it solves the problem when all columns are nullable.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Using a trigger you can something like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TEST 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.COLUMN1= :new.COLUMN2
     AND :new.COLUMN3=:new.COLUMN1
     AND  :new.COLUMN4=:new.COLUMN1
     AND :new.COLUMN5=:new.COLUMN1     

   THEN
    :new.same:='SAME';
    ELSE
    :new.same:='DIFFERENT';

    END IF;

END;
```

You can consider adding NULL condition check as well to the above trigger.

Answer (score 0):

When column 1 is defined as NOT NULL you can apply following logic: *concatenate columns 2 to 5 and remove any occurance of the string in column 1. When the result is an empty string all columns were equal (or NULL).*

```
CASE 
   WHEN OReplace(  Coalesce(COLUMN_2,'')
                 ||Coalesce(COLUMN_3,'')
                 ||Coalesce(COLUMN_4,'')
                 ||Coalesce(COLUMN_5,'')
                 ,COLUMN_1
                 ,'') = ''
   THEN COLUMN_1
   ELSE 'different'
end
```

Edit:

Ups, this was way too complicated. Much simpler:

```
CASE
   WHEN column_1 <> column_2
     OR column_1 <> column_3
     OR column_1 <> column_4
     OR column_1 <> column_5
   THEN 'different'
   ELSE column_1   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider adding a virtual column to your table:

```
alter table your_table add same as(
   case when not column_1 = all(column_2, column_3, column_4, column_5) 
        then 'DIFFERENT' 
        else column_1 
    end
);
```